# When did Aayla Secura almost fall to the Dark Side?

Tags: star-wars, episode-identification

I don't remember the exact comic, but I read one a while back where Aayla was going on a solo mission.  Yoda warned her to be careful, referencing some event where she almost fell to the Dark Side.

When did this happen?  Is there a certain book or comic where this event takes place, or is it only ever referenced?

Answer (score 3):

This occurred in the monthly comic series, *Star Wars* during its “Twilight” and “Darkness” story lines, culminating in *Star Wars* #35 (1998), “Darkness, pt. 4” where Quinlan Vos rescues Secura after she apprentices herself to dark Jedi Karkko.

Due to an unfortunate series of events, Jedi Quinlan Vos kills Secura’s uncle. She is overcome with desire for vengeance and this tempts her to the Dark Side.